# Iterate through all children of an element

Tags: 7, forms

I have a Drupal code below:

```
function myid_create_template($form, &$form_state){ 
    $form['myid_templates_editor']['#access'] = TRUE;    
    foreach (element_children($form['myid_templates_editor']) as $child1)   {
        $form['myid_templates_editor'][$child1]['#access'] = TRUE;

    }     
    return $form;
}
```

This code iterate to the first child only of an element, but not the child with degree 2 or more. How will I iterate it to all child/grandchild of the element?

Answer (score 4):

A simple recursive function will do the trick:

```
function allow_access(&$root_element) {
  $root_element['#access'] = TRUE;
  foreach (element_children($root_element) as $key) {
    allow_access($root_element[$key]);
  }
}
allow_access($form);
```

Comment: This is what I've been looking for. I thought it would work but unfortunately not. I updated my post above and will gladly appreciate you  if u could point me into the right direction. Thanks :)

Comment: This should work fine with a slight modification - you need to check that $root_element is an array. Otherwise element_children throws a warning.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you will have to manually add support for 2nd/3rd/etc. levels.

Didn't test the code, but this should point you in the right direction:

```
function myid_create_template($form, &$form_state){ 
  $form['myid_templates_editor']['#access'] = TRUE;    
  foreach (element_children($form['myid_templates_editor']) as $child1) {
    // Check if this element is a parent of another element.
    if (count(element_children($form['myid_templates_editor'][$child1]))) {
      foreach (element_children($form['myid_templates_editor']) as $child2) {
        if (count(element_children($form['myid_templates_editor'][$child1][$child2]))) {
          foreach (element_children($form['myid_templates_editor']) as $child3) {
            // You can continue to search for more levels here, if necessary.
          }
        }
        else {
          $form['myid_templates_editor'][$child1][$child2][$child3]['#access'] = TRUE;
        }
      }
    }
    // This is just a regular element.
    else {
      $form['myid_templates_editor'][$child1]['#access'] = TRUE;
    }
  }     

  return $form;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea but what if I had 100'th degree child? Do I have to hard code all of those? I guess recursion will do the trick, but I dont know how to implement it. :)